# What Does X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown Do?

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate2

The only way I can validate a certificate is by setting the VerificationFlags property of the X509ChainPolicy object to the IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown flag.

The certificate I'm validating is a valid ssl certificate, created by me from a CA certificate which I also created. The Certification Path tab of the certificate (viewed in Windows Explorer) shows no problems with a message *This certificate is OK.*

If I do not use the IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown flag, I get a StatusInformation that *The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.*

So, I'm not sure why I'm getting that and need to use the flag at all. Here is some code:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var cert = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "DaveSvrCert", false
    )[0];

var chain = new X509Chain();
var policy = new X509ChainPolicy
{
    RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
    RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
    VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown
};

chain.ChainPolicy = policy;

if (!chain.Build(cert))
{
    foreach (var chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
    {
        foreach (var chainElementStatus in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(chainElementStatus.Status + ": ");
            Console.WriteLine(chainElementStatus.StatusInformation);
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown` ignores `RevocationOffline` errors. These errors are caused when CA is improperly configured and do not provide certificate revocation information:

- issued certificate do not contains `CRL Distiribution Points` certificate extension
- `CRL Distiribution Points` is presented, but none of the URLs are accessible by the client.

Some applications use this flag by default, however I would strongly recommend to fix this issue by including CDP extension with globally available and accessible URLs for CRL download.

And do not use this flag, as it opens a security breach when client successfully validates and accepts revoked certificate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do a bit of further research about CDP etc. I don't really plan to host a CA update point anywhere. But maybe I need to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Crypt32's answer and recommendation is great, but obviously there are use-cases where you might not want to verify, or simply can't verify the CRL because it can't be reached over the network.  In those cases, you can set the

```
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
```

and it will completely skip the check, for all certificates in the chain (potentially saving some time, like the network timeout).

P.S. When viewing a certificate in Windows, by just double clicking it and getting the certificate properties dialog, Windows will not perform a CRL check when showing *This certificate is OK*.  That message is only determined by the fact that you trust the issuing certificate(s).